# How to make a client-server android application?

Tags: android, development-environment

I want to make a client-server android application. Specifically, they will both behave as a client and as a server as well.
In simple words, I want two apps, who should be able to send data (Email address, login credentials, and anything I want to send) via the Internet.
I checked for such an app on Github but unable to find one. Any leads would be really helpful.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please refer here to see if it is useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/35052840/4123990

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is using a server to store the data from both apps.
Suppose you have 2 apps, the App A and the App B.

**Use case**
App A want to send info to App B.
**Solution**
App A -> Server -> App B.

**Use case**
App B want to send info to App A.
**Solution**
App B -> Server -> App A.

If you want to communicate the apps directly and the devices are in the same network you can check this: [App that will communicate between devices connected on the same local network Wi-Fi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493067/app-that-will-communicate-between-devices-connected-on-the-same-local-network-wi)

Answer (score -2):

if you build a client-server system of an andriod app in any apps you are new to open android studio create a project file and the inner main file have app.java or app.kln. write code for building applications and run perfectly . that is the basic stap way to building app development.